# How does overriding `method_missing` work?

Tags: ruby, method-missing

```
o = Object.new

def o.method_missing(m,*args)
  puts "xxxxxxx #{m}"
end

p o.some_method
```

What is the underlying process of overriding a method?

Answer (score 2):

> how does the new method know that I am calling a missing method

If a called method is not defined, it can tell that you are calling a missing method.

> how does it print the output of the new method?

By executing the new defined method.

> How is `some_method` considered as the `m` argument?

By design.

Comment: I have a feeling you did not understand me.